# Additional dock showing

Tags: 18.04, themes, dock

I've been playing a little with themes, and now for some reason I got an additional (original one is down) dock showing, and I'm not sure what made it appear and how to remove it.

[image: screenshot of the additional dock]

It shows maybe 20 seconds after booting Linux, and doesn't go away.

Answer (score 0):

The additional dock was appearing because of wbar.

If you go to task manager

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

you will see wbar running, and it will disappear when you end that process.

To remove it permanently, follow these instructions: http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/w/wbar/uninstall/index.html

than after restart, it won't be showing again.